# In .NET 4.0, What is the default implementation of Equals for value types?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

The two documentation pages seem to contradict on this topic:

- [ValueType.Equals Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dts52z7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)  says "The default implementation of the Equals method **uses reflection** to compare the corresponding fields of obj and this instance."
- [Object.Equals Method (Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)  says "The default implementation of Equals supports reference equality for reference types, and **bitwise equality for value types**."

So is it bitwise equality or reflection?

I took a glimpse at the source code of `ValueType` and found a comment saying

> // if there are no GC references in this object we can avoid reflection
>
> // and do a fast memcmp

Can someone clarify what "GC reference" means? I guess it's a field having a reference type but I'm not sure.

If I create a `struct` which only has value type fields, will the instances of it be always compared the fast way?

**UPDATE:** The documentation for.Net 4.5 has been significantly improved: it is free from the mentioned contradiction and now gives a better understanding how the default value type equality checking works.

Comment: Although this doesn't answer your question, it's also worth noting that value types should override Equals and operator equals. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182276.aspx

Comment: I was about to ask the same question ;)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

[**`System.ValueType.Equals`**](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/valuetype.cs,23) is special. It does the following steps, in order, until it gets some result:

1. If the `obj` comparing to is 'null', it returns `false`.
2. If the `this` and `obj` arguments are different types, it returns `false`.
3. If the type is "blittable" it compares the memory images. If they are identical, it returns `true`.
4. Finally, it uses reflection to call `Equals` the paired-up instance fields for each value. If any of those fields are not equal, it returns `false`. Otherwise it returns `true`. Note that it never calls the base method, `Object.Equals`.

Because it uses reflection to compare the fields, you should ***always override*** `Equals` on any `ValueType` you create.  Reflection is slow.

When it's a "GCReference", or a field in the struct that is a reference type, it winds up using reflection on each field to do the comparison.  It has to do this, because the `struct` actually has a pointer to the reference type's location on the heap.

If there is no reference type used in the struct, and they are the same type, the fields are guaranteed to be in the same order, and be the same size in memory, so it can just compare the bare memory.

For a struct with only value types for fields, i.e. a struct with only one `int` field, no reflection is done during a comparison.  None of the fields reference anything on the heap, so there is no `GCReference` or `GCHandle`.  Furthermore, any instance of this structure will have the same in-memory layout of the fields (with a few minor exceptions), so the CLR team can do a direct memory comparison (memcmp), which is much faster than the other option.

So yes, if you only have value types in your structure, it will do the faster memcmp, instead of the reflection comparison, but you may not want to do that.  Keep reading.

This **does not** mean you should use the default `Equals` implementation.  In fact, do not do that.  Stop it.  It's doing bit comparisons, which are *not* always accurate.  What is that you say?  Let me show you:

```
private struct MyThing
{
    public float MyFloat;
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyThing f, s;
    f.MyFloat = 0.0f;
    s.MyFloat = -0.0f;

    Console.WriteLine(f.Equals(s));  // prints False
    Console.WriteLine(0.0f == -0.0f); // prints True
}
```

The numbers are equal mathematically, but they are not equal in their binary representation.  So, I will stress it again, **do not rely on the default implementation of ValueType.Equals**

Comment: Yes, good answer. You could stress that the answer on the last question is "Yes".

Comment: So, I assume, if you know what you are doing, for example, if you only have int fields, you can rely on the default implementation. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @Gebb - You don't have to know what you're doing to use it.  You can rely on *Microsoft's* default implementation, but since it's not part of the standard, you may find the code acts different on Mono, or even .NET CE.  Also, the behavior may change in the future, since it's not set in stone by the standard, anyway.  Microsoft recommends you override the default implementation, which is ultimately the best choice.  Whatever small performance boost you may get would be negligible, if at all measurable.

Comment: Actually, one could argue that the "default" behavior for `Equals` ends up being the right one.  For example, if one has a formula which is expensive to compute, and one wishes to cache parameter values and results in a dictionary, it would be possible that passing `0.0` to a formula may yield a different result from passing `-0.0`, and thus the dictionary *should* regard the values as distinct.  Too bad there's no clean way (so far as I know) to test whether two float, double, or `Decimal` values are "really" equal.

Comment: I don't understand why they didn't just make the c# compiler or the CLR automatically add a reasonable default implementation to any value types that didn't explicitly specify one. 99% of the time it's the exact same boilerplate over and over for every value type.

Comment: @supercat `0.0f` and `-0.0f` both return hashcode `0` and return `true` for equals so dictionaries would consider them to be the same key as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Not being a real expert in this field I would just go ahead and put my thoughts:
The documentation (according to me) states that if your struct has a field that is object (reference type) reflection **can not** be avoided.

So if you have the following:

```
    public struct SomeStruct
    {
        public object ObjectTest
    }
```

The ObjectTest cannot be compared without reflection. So reflection will be used. This part of the text seems to say I am right:

> "**ValueType.Equals** - The default implementation of the Equals method uses reflection to compare the corresponding fields of obj and this instance."