# Strange behavior of Equals method

Tags: c#, .net

According to this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8315745/5324847
.Net should compare value types by reflection or bitwise. But if we look at this code we can see it's neither (or both of them at once??).

```
//Bitwise test
//if .Net compares bitwise then last line should be false
//if it uses reflections then last line should be true
float a = -0.0f;
float b = 0.0f;
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("",BitConverter.GetBytes(a))); //prints 000128
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("",BitConverter.GetBytes(b))); //prints 0000
Console.WriteLine(a == b); //True
Console.WriteLine(a.Equals(b)); //prints True


//Reflection test
//if .Net compares using reflection then last line should be false
//if it uses bitwise comparsion then last line should be true
a = float.NaN;
b = float.NaN;
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("",BitConverter.GetBytes(a))); //prints 00192255
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("",BitConverter.GetBytes(b))); //prints 00192255
Console.WriteLine(a == b); //False
Console.WriteLine(a.Equals(b)); //prints True
```

If we wrap the variable in structure .Net uses bitwise comparsion.
Proof:

```
public struct FloatS
{
    public float x; 
}
public static void Main()
{
    //bitwise test
    //if .Net compares bitwise then last line should be false
    //if it uses reflections then last line should be true
    FloatS a = new FloatS();
    FloatS b = new FloatS();
    a.x = -0.0f;
    b.x = 0.0f;
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("",BitConverter.GetBytes(a.x))); //prints 000128
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("",BitConverter.GetBytes(b.x))); //prints 0000
    Console.WriteLine(a.x == b.x); //True
    Console.WriteLine(a.Equals(b)); //prints False -- this time corectly because it's bitwise comparsion


    //Reflection test
    //if .Net compares using reflection then last line should be false
    //if it uses bitwise comparsion then last line should be true
    a.x = float.NaN;
    b.x = float.NaN;
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("",BitConverter.GetBytes(a.x))); //prints 00192255
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("",BitConverter.GetBytes(b.x))); //prints 00192255
    Console.WriteLine(a.x == b.x); //False
    Console.WriteLine(a.Equals(b)); //prints True - also corectly
}
```

My asumption was that .Net uses difrent implementation of Equals for primitive types. But that seems incorect because both float and struct type can be cast to [System.ValueType](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/valuetype.cs).

Can anybody explain what is happening?

Comment: Any value type can provide it's own implementation of equality operator and Equals method. What you describe is "default" behavior if you did not do that. And of course float and other primitive types do provide such implementation.

Comment: good to know @HansPassant. I've just realized that `Console.WriteLine(float.NaN == float.NaN);` print false, which is super weird to me!

Comment: and checking [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/single.cs,dda909df0f8d2fd0) does not help me to understand this behavior: @HansPassant, what is the method operator where the magic happes?

Comment: @GianPaolo you won't find that in reference source, because when you compare floats (or ints etc) - in is compiled to special `ceq` IL instruction (or other similar instuctions depending on context), not actual `==` operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> According to ... .NET should compare value types by reflection or bitwise.

You're misreading that answer, which is about **user-defined value types**.

- For `==`, floats are compared using special instructions just for floats.  Zero and negative zero are equal, NaN equals nothing, not even itself, and so on.
- Any type can override `Equals`, and `System.Single` does so.  `x.Equals(y)` on floats has the semantics of `(x == y) || (IsNaN(x) && IsNaN(y))`. I do not know for certain why `Equals` and `==` were made to have different behaviour, though probably it was to ensure that `Equals` on floats is an equivalence relation, which is necessary for certain applications such as putting floats into a hash table. (UPDATE: My supposition is correct; see comment below.)

If you write a user-defined value type and do not provide your own `Equals` then you get the default one, which as you note has two big problems:

- It is sometimes not efficient
- A struct that wraps a float does not automatically get float equality behaviour.  More generally, a struct that wraps a T does not automatically get T equality behaviour.

> My assumption was that .NET uses different implementation of Equals for primitive types. But that seems incorrect because both float and struct type can be cast to System.ValueType.

This paragraph makes zero sense to me, and so either I am misunderstanding you, or you believe something completely false about inheritance. Every type can override `Equals`. What does that have to do with the fact that user code can box any non-nullable value type? I don't see the connection between your two sentences, and the fact that you believe there is one indicates that someone has a wrong belief here.

Comment: I see in reference source that `System.Single` also provides implementation for `==` operator (which does `return left == right;`). Is there any case when this implementation actually used (so this operator actually called)? Or is it just to satisfy compiler, or maybe for consistency?

Comment: @Evk: Great question!  The compiler will ignore the user-defined operators entirely; all the code to deal with arithmetic on built-in types including overload resolution and code generation is special-cased in the compiler.  That's why you can get away with an `==` operator that appears to be in an infinite recursion for built-in types!  Those user-defined operators are there so that people writing their own languages do not have to do the same work that the C# compiler team does.  They can generate method calls if they like.

Comment: @Evk: More generally, many of the normal rules are relaxed in the compiler for the situation where the base class library team is compiling built in System types itself.  For example, `struct Int32 { int value; }` should be illegal because a struct cannot contain one of itself, but that rule is turned off if the compiler knows that mscorlib is being compiled.

Comment: Thanks, I've started reading all your SO answers some days ago, sorted by votes, and just 10 minutes ago got to the one explaining this behavior (with an example of int containing int) :)

Comment: Ecma-355, partition I, chapter 8.2.5.2: "Note: Although two floating point NaNs are defined by IEC 60559:1989 to always compare as
unequal, the contract for System.Object.Equals requires that overrides must satisfy the
requirements for an equivalence operator. Therefore, System.Double.Equals and
System.Single.Equals return True when comparing two NaNs, while the equality operator
returns False in that case, as required by the IEC standard."

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks for looking that up!