# Where is == operator defined in Class "object"?

Tags: c#, .net

I searched the source code of [FCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framework_Class_Library), and I got confused that `string.Equals()` uses `Object.ReferenceEquals()`, and `Object.ReferenceEquals()` uses `==` operator to jugde. And then I can't find how the `==` operator is defined.

So where is the original operator defined?

Comment: Im pretty  sure its part of the C# language itself and not part of objects.

Comment: it's feature derived from C# language. **By default, the operator == tests for reference equality by determining if two references indicate the same object, so reference types do not need to implement operator == in order to gain this functionality.** - from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx#Anchor_1)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is an operator that the language uses to validate that two values are the same. When your code would be compiled this operator would be compiled appropriately in CIL and then when we will be executed by the CLR the two values would be compared to be checked if they are the same.

For instance, this is the CIL code for the `Main` method:

[image]

that the compiler produces for the following program (it's a console application):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a = 3;
        int b = 4;
        bool areEqual = a == b;
        Console.WriteLine(areEqual);
    }
}
```

Note the IL_0007 line. There a `ceq` instruction has been emitted. This is that you are looking for, the `==` operator.

**Important Note**

This is happening when the `==` is not overloaded.

Answer (score 18):

When there isn't an overloaded `==` operator (as here), the compiler emits a [`ceq`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ceq.aspx) instruction. There's no more C# code to look at at this point.

> Compares two values. If they are equal, the integer value 1 (int32) is pushed onto the evaluation stack; otherwise 0 (int32) is pushed onto the evaluation stack.

Answer (score 5):

Overloading `operator==` in C# is syntactic sugar for calling a static function. The overload resolution, like all overload resolution, happens based on the *static type* of the object, not the dynamic type. Let's look at [`Object.ReferenceEquals`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/object.cs,4d607d6d56a93c7e) again:

```
public static bool ReferenceEquals (Object objA, Object objB) {
    return objA == objB;
}
```

Here, the static type of `objA` and `objB` is `Object`.  The dynamic type can be anything; a string, some other user defined type, whatever; that does not matter. The determination of which `operator==` is called is determined statically when this function is compiled, so you always get the default, non-overloaded, built in language-supplied one. .NET could just have not had a `ReferenceEquals` and let users do `((object)a) == ((object)b)`, but having a specific named function to say what's going on improves clarity.

`Object.Equals`, on the other hand, is just a virtual function. As a result, which `Equals` is chosen is based on the dynamic type of the object to the left of the `.Equals(`, like any other virtual function call.

Answer (score 4):

[`ceq`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ceq.aspx) takes two values from the stack and gives results. If the result value is 1 then they are considered equal and 0 if they are not equal.

However, the `==` operator doesn't always get translated to `ceq`.
Whether `==` in C# results in `ceq` depends on some more factors like `are data types primitives` or `do they have custom == operators` or `are they references`.