# Check if 2 objects contain the same data in fields

Tags: c#, .net, list, object, equality

I have a `Pharmacy` class which contains lots of properties, and a `Pharmacy` is declared as unique by having the `ID` property as a key.

I have code in place which fetches all rows in a table from MySQL back to `Pharmacy` objects with their properties.

I want compare two `List<Pharmacy>` objects for the entries in them and check if the same `ID` exists in both tables, if it doesn't exist then add it to a new `List<Pharmacy`. If the `ID` exists in both but the data in the objects differs, then save that object to a new `List<Pharmacy` aswell.

This is how the class looks like.

```
public class Pharmacy
{
    [Key]
    public string Tunniste { get; set; }
    public string Lyhenne { get; set; }
    public string PitkaNimi { get; set; }
    public string YlempiYksikko { get; set; }
    public string Hierarkiataso { get; set; }
    public string VoimassaoloAlkaa { get; set; }
    public string VoimassaoloPaattyy { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

It's in Finnish but I hope you can live with that. 
Here's how I've tried to check if they're identical.

```
        for (int i = 0; i != pharmacyListFromArchive.Count; i++)
        {
            if (pharmacyListFromArchive[i].Equals(pharmacyListFromNew[i]))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Objects are identical.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Objects are NOT identical. {0} - {1}", pharmacyListFromArchive[i].Tunniste, pharmacyListFromNew[i].Tunniste);
            }
        }
```

But when I run that, none of the objects register as identical even though they are identical in data. How can I work around this?

Comment: You have to override `Equals` to compare the ID property, otherwise only references are compared

Comment: Serialize both objects and compare the resulting strings, could be an option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard implementation of `Equals` checks only for reference equality. [What is the default behavior of Equals Method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632369/what-is-the-default-behavior-of-equals-method)

You can either override the behavior of `Equals`. [Guidelines for Overriding Equals() and Operator == (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147.aspx).

```
public class Pharmacy  {
   // fields ...

   public override bool Equals(object obj) {
       // If parameter is null return false.
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }

        // If parameter cannot be cast to Pharmacy return false.
        Pharmacy p = obj as Pharmacy;
        if ((System.Object)p == null) {
            return false;
        }

        // Return true if the fields match:
        return p.Lyhenne == this.Lyhenne &&
               p.PitkaNimi == this.PitkaNimi
               // && etc...
        ;
   }

    public override int GetHashCode() {
        return Lyhenne.GetHashCode() ^ PitkaNimi.GetHashCode() /* ^ etc ... */;
    }
}
```

Or you implement a custom `IEqualityComparer` [IEqualityComparer Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx). This might be preferable if your ORM Mapper relies on the default equals (like Entity Framework does).